# Create mongoDB Session with Socket.io connection only

Tags: mongodb, express, ionic-framework, socket.io, express-session

I need to create a session on MongoDB when the socket connection start, I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'CONNECTION TO MONGODB',
  collection: 'sessions',
    connectionOptions: { 
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
});

// Catch errors
store.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

let sessionConfig = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'This is a secret',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
  },
  store: store,
  httpOnly: false,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

app.use(sessionConfig);

io.use(sharedsession(sessionConfig, {
  autoSave:true
})); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('<html><head><script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script><script>var socket = io();</script></head><body>Test</body></html>');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log('socket.handshake',socket.handshake.session);
  console.log(socket.handshake.xdomain);
  console.log("A USER LOGGED IN WITH ID: ", socket.request.user); 

  // Accept a login event with user's data
  socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
    socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
    socket.handshake.session.save();
  });

  socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
    if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
      delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
      socket.handshake.session.save();
    }
  });        

});

http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

server = app.listen(3000);
```

If I access to , the session is created successfully in MongoDB, I understand that the configuration with express is ok, and the Socket Share that session correctly when I try to connect from the same domain.

The problem is, that I have a mobile app with ionic v4, that only access from a socket connection and the session is never created on MongoDB.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE 1:

I try to add passport.socketio to get a proper way to add authentication to my app, and the output of this code, is Not Session found, its right, the socket connection never add the session to the MongoDB:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");
let passport = require('passport');
let passportSocketIo = require("passport.socketio");
let cors = require('cors')

var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'MONGO DB STRING CONNECTION',
  collection: 'sessions',
    connectionOptions: { 
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
});

// Catch errors
store.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 

let config = {
  passport : passport,
  secret: 'This is a secret',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
  },
  store: store,
  httpOnly: false,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
  fail:         onAuthorizeFail 
};

let sessionConfig = require('express-session')(config);
app.use(sessionConfig);

io.origins('*:*');

io.use(sharedsession(sessionConfig, passportSocketIo.authorize(config))); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('<html><head><script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script><script>var socket = io();</script></head><body>Test</body></html>');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log('socket.handshake',socket.handshake.session);
  console.log(socket.handshake.xdomain);
  console.log("A USER LOGGED IN WITH ID: ", socket.request.user); 

  // Accept a login event with user's data
  socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
    socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
    socket.handshake.session.save();
  });

  socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
    if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
      delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
      socket.handshake.session.save();
    }
  });        

});

http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

server = app.listen(3000);

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
  console.log('successful connection to socket.io');
  // accept(); //Let the user through
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){

  console.log("Errror",error);

  if(error) accept(new Error(message));
  console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);
  // accept(null, false);
}
```

Comment: I've recently encountered almost the same issue. The difference was I was using redis instead of mongo. Have you check what's in the raw headers?

Comment: I notice that the socket.handshake.xdomain is false when I access from the browser, and is socket.handshake.xdomain true when I access from the mobile app. I don't know if this is related.

Comment: Actually I don't know what xdomain does.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Before io.on('connection.... 
io​.​engine​.​generateId​ ​=​ (​req​) ​=>​ {

//Try to get the cookie out from
//req.rawHeaders and return it
//so the socket ID will equal to the session Id


});

//The connection event
​io​.​on​(​'​connection​'​, ​socket​ ​=>​ { ....

//You can then do a mongoose search query using the socket Id here to match the user in the db
```

Comment: req is empty: io.engine.generateId(req=>{ console.log(req);}) doesn't have anything.

Comment: Are you making the request through web or phone

Comment: Yes, from mobile app with ionic v4

Comment: Do you have some sort of login functionality on the ionic app?

Comment: No, nothing, const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3001', 
options: {
  query: 'session_id=' + myCookie
}
}; the connection works without session or passport config, but if the session doesn't exist, the socket connection doesn't created.. it seems that the session is created only if I access from the URL in a browser.

Comment: You should have some sort of login functionality on the mobile app in order for a session to be established. The browser and the mobile app will have different sessions.